Were there (licensed) female medicine practitioners in the Middle Ages?
I'm reading A History of Medicine by Lois N. Magner (2nd edition). On page 154 there is a line saying:

For example, in some parts of France, women could practice medicine or surgery if they passed an examination.

This sounds rather unlikely to me, as I can't imagine people need to pass examination to gain any certificate this sort of thing occurs in Middle Ages, even more unlikely to me is that medieval people are open-minded enough to allow women gain such certificate.
Does anyone know sources of this statement?

There was indeed an examination, by men of course. I came across some very interesting reading by Dr. Isabella Gagliardi and Dr. Catherine Normand (in French). And "Scola Salernitana". What was your preliminary research prior to this question?

@OldPadawan Many thanks, this really helps!

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hildegard_of_Bingen for instance?

@OldPadawan - Huh. Like the poster, I found the idea of there being any kind of formal medical examination and/or licensing back in the Middle Ages the most outlandish concept in the question. The MO for skilled professions back then was usually the apprenticeship system. Perhaps consider making an answer of that comment?

A good article on the organizations controlling this during late medieval can be read here.

@T.E.D.: might do that when I have time to split and point the informative parts, and translate the sources, as there are french and Italian (loads of work though). And, as we're on the 24th, Merry Christmas to y'all folks!

@OldPadawan - I would have gotten mad at someone for suggesting this 5 years ago, but Google Translations have gotten IMHO usably good. I'm generally not in favor of putting "AI" content in answers here, but a well-marked AI translation I believe will now do in a pinch.

Midwifes were exclusively women and there are examples of guild-like regulations from the late middle ages, e.g. from Regensburg in 1452. The Regensburg regulations are not much concerned with training or examinations (other such regulations apparently are), but they definitely amount to certification/licensing.

... auch damit keine Frau, die nicht dazu eingesetzt und geschworen ist, sich keiner gebärenden Frau unterwinde, es sei denn mindestens eine geschworenen Hebamme dabei, haben meine Herren die Hebammen, wie sie am Ende dieser Schrift mit Namen benannt und aufgeschrieben sind', aufgenommen, diese hernach geschriebenen Artikel von Wort zu Wort hören und schwören lassen. Und welche Frau fortan mehr zur Hebamme aufgenommen wird, soll desgleichen die Artikel auch hören und schwören, so oft man eine aufnimmt.


... and in order that no woman, who is not authorized and sworn in, approaches (?) a woman in labour, except together with at least one sworn-in midwife, my lords have made those midwifes who are recorded at the end of this document hear the following articles word for word and give their oaths. And whoever is recorded as a midwive in the future shall hear the articles and give her oath as well.

This is very late in the Middle Ages, and even late in the Late Middle Ages. Additionally, the wording of these regulations makes it sound (to me) as if they were an innovation and not a simple continuation of what had been done before.
But here we have whole branch of medicine performed by women. And even if licensing for midwives seems to have been a late innovation, in general access controls for skilled professions should not come as a surprise when talking about medieval towns and cities.

Interesting that the midwives had to "hear" the articles. Probably illiterate?

I'd call 1452 as Renaissance rather than "Middle Ages", the latter being something more like pre-1400, give or take.

@PieterGeerkens Not in Regensburg: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A4tmittelalter

@TheHonRose - Seems likely, although another possibility is that it was considered a more certain method of information transmission than just handing someone some papers and asking them to sign at the bottom that they read it all.

@PieterGeerkens - For me the boundary is the printing press, which was invented around 1440, so I was thinking the same thing. However, it is right on the boundary, and clearly was A Thing that was happening then, since this is a recording of standard practice, not an exceptional event. The 1309 example njuffa came up with is pretty solidly Medieval.

@njuffa - Dive a bit deeper into that WP page, and we have a more complex explanation:  "For Europe as a whole, 1500 is often considered to be the end of the Middle Ages, but there is no universally agreed upon end date. Depending on the context, events such as the conquest of Constantinople by the Turks in 1453, Christopher Columbus's first voyage to the Americas in 1492, or the Reformation in 1517 are sometimes used. English historians often use the Battle of Bosworth Field in 1485 to mark the end of the period...."

There's more there for Spain, and one suspects every country has some flagstone event they'd like to use. But for my money, nothing happened in Europe within 500 years +- that was even in the same ballpark of socially impactful as the invention and popularization of the Printing Press, which coincidentally (not) happened in the 1430's and snowballed from there. The difference in amount and speed of information transmission in European society before and after is so massively quantitative that its qualitative. So yeah, 1452 for me is hanging on the line.

Licensed female medical practitioners may have been rare during the Middle Ages, but they did exist. While I have yet to find an example from France, here is one from Portugal.
Iona McCleery, "Medical licensing in late-medieval Portugal." In: Wendy Turner and Sara Butler (eds.), Medicine and the Law in the Middle Ages, Brill 2014, pp. 196-219. On p. 201:

There is some evidence that Portuguese towns had a system of licensing as they sometimes sent candidates to the royal court to have their practice confirmed. For example, in 1454 Isabel Martins, the only woman to be licensed during the fifteenth century, was licensed in surgery at the request of her town Montemor-o-Velho.
[...]
Nothing is known about how practitioners gained access to the itinerant Portuguese royal court or how they used their copies of the royal license. It is clear that royal physicians or surgeons, referred to as "chiefs" of their occupation (físico-mor or cirurgião-mor), carried out the main system of licensing.

Here is a second example, from the Italian peninsula:
Zohra Faqiri, The Medical Practice and Licencing of Women in the Late Medieval Kingdom of Naples. M.A. Thesis, University of Waterloo 2020. On p. 1:

In September 1309, the Neapolitan royal court issued a licence to Maria Gallicia to practice surgery throughout the kingdom. Maria’s licence was one of thousands preserved from the Angevin ruled, late medieval Kingdom of Naples. Maria’s surgical licence was unique within the kingdom as it was one of twenty-four the crown granted to women, and the only one granted to a woman without territorial limitations. Perhaps the uniqueness of her licence had to do with her surgical speciality: the cure of wounds, abscesses, and hernias of the womb.

The thesis describes the process of becoming licensed in the Kingdom of Naples on p. 12:

In medieval Naples, the licensing of individuals fell under the jurisdiction of the royal physicians or surgeons, depending on the type of licence. One or two masters examined candidates, and if deemed competent, the officials signed documentation detailing the parameters or scope of the licensee’s practice. Less commonly, officials sometimes also accepted letters of credentials by teachers indicating an individual’s qualifications in order to grant a licence. The masters granted licences for the medical practice of physicians or surgeons, however none pertained to barber-surgeons or apothecaries.

